# How to create dynamic list of clickable links through Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I want to create a dynamic list of links in a div called `img_list`, when i click on any one it will open in the adjacent `iframe` through  Ajax calls.

So I did the following:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div id="img_list">
        </div>
        <iframe id="img_loc" width="300" class="modal-content"
            height="500"
            allowfullscreen data-token="3Az3ki"></iframe>
        <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
```

---

```
 var imageList = function (projId, locCode) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SeventhNavi.aspx/ListImages",
                data: JSON.stringify({ projId: projId, locCode: locCode }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false
            });

        };
```

---

```
modal.style.display = "block";
            imageList(1, 'G11').done(function (data) {
                var appenddata;
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    appenddata += "<a href = '" + value.loc_path + " '>" + value.description + " </a>";
                });
                $('#img_list').html(appenddata);

            });
```

---

My returned `Json` Object is like this:

```
[{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:DM_IBM_S360.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Eniac.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Cray_2_Arts_et_Metiers_dsc03940.jpg"}]
```

---

This code does not work !

Comment: what error have got in console?

Comment: @programtreasures No errors just `value.loc_path`,`value.description` is undefined although the `imageList` function return the Json data

Comment: What is the output of `value`?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell : `udefined`, i try to loop through the Json object and set the `href` and the link name properties

Comment: So the done's data returns the JSON object described above but the $.each's value is undefined?

Comment: Apart from this issue, target attribute should also be there in <a>

Comment: @SILENT no `value.loc_path` is undefined

Comment: But you told @ChrisSatchell that the output of value is `undefined`? If not, what is the output?

Comment: Are you sure `data` is even an object?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell the result of `alert(data.d);` outside the loop is: `[{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:DM_IBM_S360.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Eniac.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Cray_2_Arts_et_Metiers_dsc03940.jpg"}]`

Comment: @SILENT the result of `alert(data.d);` outside the loop is: `[{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:DM_IBM_S360.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Eniac.jpg"},{"description":"demo","loc_path":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#/media/File:Cray_2_Arts_et_Metiers_dsc03940.jpg"}]`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare If `data.d` contains the data, why are you looping over `data` and not `data.d`?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell because when i alert   `alert(data.d.length);` i get the number of characters and it's like a string!! not JSON object, i feel there's something wrong in my code

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Is your data.d a stringified response? If so, use `JSON.parse`. Also, I would recommend using `let` or `const` instead of `var` in case its a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @SILENT I do the following :

```
imageList(1, 'G11').done(function (data) {
                let appenddata = '';
                data.d = JSON.parse(data.d); //Fix the problem
                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                    if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value) {
                        appenddata += "<a href = '#' id = '" + value.loc_serial + "'" + ">" + "<img border='0' alt= '" + value.description + "'" + " src= '" + value.thumbnail + "'" + " width='100' height='100' > " + " </a> ";
                        appenddata += " <input id = '" + value.loc_serial + "'" + " type='hidden' " + " value= '" + value.loc_path + "'" + "> "
                    }
                });
                $('#img_list').html(appenddata);

            });
```

---

Parsing the data to JSON object fixed my problem :

> data.d = JSON.parse(data.d);

Answer (score 1):

The API returning array of the objects, you need to access it through index,

```
        modal.style.display = "block";
        imageList(1, 'G11').done(function (data) {
            var appenddata;
            for(var i =0 ; i<data.length; i++){
                appenddata += "<a href = '" + data[i].loc_path + " '>" + data[i].description + " </a>";
            }
            $('#img_list').html(appenddata);

        });
```

Comment: Are you sure? To my understanding [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) works with Arrays as well

Comment: This doesnot work because i use ` data: JSON.stringify({ projId: projId, locCode: locCode })` so data can't be handled like this, Could you recommend some way to solve this problem